# System center 2016 with VMM un-recommended configuration

Tags: system-center, scvmm

​I have Windows 2016 host running with the Hyper-V role running. There will only be a few VM's running and there's less than 10 actual users so activity will be minimal.
I have 3 options from management on this which are both not best practices by any means. 
I can do either of the following:

1.Install **SCCM w/ VMM** on the domain controller (but it complains that it's not recommended to install SQL server during the install)

2.Install everything on the Hyper-V Host.

3.Split install between the host and DC guest.

What would you do when separate VM's are not approved for this implementation?

Comment: sc-vmm seems a little more than you may need. You also don't have the resources to deploy it correctly. In that case I wouldn't install it

Comment: it is in preparation for additional hardware coming in a couple months that will be a HA cluster configuration.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Are you asking which is the best way to deploy SCVMM? Additionally, SCVMM isn't required to deploy a Hyper-V failover cluster.